# Is the Sum and Absolute Difference of two positive Integers Unique?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

**Question:**

Is the combination of Sum and Absolute Difference of 2 positive integers unique to that combination of integers?

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are positive integers AND $X \neq Y$.

I think that we all agree that: $X + Y = Y + X$ AND $|X - Y| = |Y - X|$

However I don't think there is any other positive integers ($A$ and $B$, $A \neq B$) where $A + B = X + Y$ AND $|A - B| = |X - Y|$ AND ($A \neq X$ OR $A \neq Y$) AND ($B \neq X$ OR $B \neq Y$) )

**Background**

Over on the [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/261309/best-way-to-model-the-relationship-of-unique-pairs) there is a question asking for ensuring the uniqueness of a relationship.  In the specific implementation it is really a comparison of 2 positive integers that represent objects in a relationship.

Lets say for example that we are modeling that Kirk and Victoria are friends.  If Kirk = 1 and Victoria = 2 in this table, then I need on instance of either [1,2] or [2,1] but I don't need both.  (Since it can be inferred that if Kirk is friends with Victoria, that Victoria is also friends with Kirk)

Another avenue for testing I was attempting is to use some basic arithmetic to create a summary of the 2 integers (which computers can calculate and compare quickly).  I ran a test of all combinations of positive integers from 1 - 10,000 and logged the Sum, Product and Absolute Difference of the 2 integers.

It appeared from my testing that the Combination of Sum and Absolute Difference was unique for the combination.  EX: The Sum and Absolute Difference of [1,2] and [2,1] were the same, but was not shared with any other pair of [x,y] and [y,x].

In my head this makes sense, because you can make changes to the two integers in question to create the same Sum or Absolute Difference but that would change the value for the other attribute.  EX: [2,5] as a Sum of 7 and an Absolute Difference of 3.  [1,6] has the same Sum but a different Absolute Difference, and [3,6] has the same Absolute Difference but a different Sum.

I am assuming I am not the first person to see this relationship and this has either been proven to be true or this has been proven to be false, and I either did not find the cases where it is false or my comparison methods were wrong.

Comment: Do you know the answer for the related problem:  do the sum and difference determine the 2 numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Assume without loss of generality that $X\ge Y$, so $|X-Y|=X-Y$.

(If not, switch $X$ and $Y$.)

If $X+Y=S$ and $X-Y=D$, then $X=\dfrac{S+D}2$ and $Y=\dfrac{S-D}2$,

so $X$ and $Y$ are indeed uniquely determined by $S$ and $D$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us solve $s=x+y,d=|x-y|$ for $x,y$. We eliminate $y$ and get

$$d=|2x-s|$$ or $$2x-s=\pm d.$$

So

$$x=\frac{s+d}2,y=\frac{s-d}2$$ or$$x=\frac{s-d}2,y=\frac{s+d}2.$$

This shows that there are exactly two solutions.

---

Let us play the same game with sum and product: $s=x+y,p=xy$.

Multiplying by $x$,

$$sx=x^2+xy$$ or

$$x^2-sx+p=0.$$

By solving the quadratic equation,

$$x=\frac{s\pm\sqrt{s^2-4p}}2,y=\frac{s\mp\sqrt{s^2-4p}}2.$$

---

In both cases, the two solutions are deduced from each other by exchanging $x$ and $y$. This is due to the symmetry of the equations (commutativity).

Comment: Just to confirm.  Are you saying that as well the Sum-Absolute Difference combination is unique for 2 integers, that the Sum-Product combination is also unique for 2 integers?

Comment: @KirkSaunders: do you understand the method ?

Comment: I believe I do.  Multiply each side of the sum equation by $x$, that then allows you to replace $xy$ with $p$.  From there you can then solve for $x$ after knowing the values for $s$ and $p$.  A similar method could then be repeated for $y$.  I just wanted to make sure I was reading what you provided correctly.  That because of the 2 equations you provided we can infer that for any combination of Sum and Product that $x$ and $y$ can only be one possible option.  Thus meaning that no combination of could produce the same Sum and Product as $x$ and $y$ unless they were $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @KirkSaunders: what I mean is that you answer the question by writing the equations and checking the number of solutions.