# Unique Property(ies) of List of Distinct Positive Integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking for an expansion on a question I asked previously, for if the [Absolute Difference and Sum of 2 Positive Integers is Unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673016/is-the-sum-and-absolute-difference-of-two-positive-integers-unique).

**Is there some property or set of properties for a list of positive integers (where no single value repeats) that makes the list unique?**

EX: {1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13} is different than {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13} (or any any other combination of integers between 1 and **N** inclusive, where no single integer repeats), without sorting/looping through each integer in both lists and comparing that way.

I ran a test on all possible lists where the integers are between 1 and 15 inclusively (a set of 32,768 lists). EX:
{1}
,{1,2}
,...{1,3,7,15}
,...{4,5,7,11}
,...{11,12,13}
,...{13,14,15}
,...{15}

From that testing it appears, an individual list is unique on the combination of the three below attributes.

1. Product of all integers in the list
2. Arithmetic Mean of all integers in the list
3. Standard Deviation of the complete data set, rounded to 19 decimal places

Is there anything I can look at or work through to suggest that this pattern will continue if the range of integer values increases?

Comment: You could compute $\sum_{i \in S} 2^i$ which is unique as the binary representation is unique. Also $\prod_{i\in S} p_i$ is unique by fundamental theorem of arithmetic ($p_n$ is $n$-th prime).

Comment: @Sil - Thank you for taking the time to provide some thoughts. Can you explain a little more on what you mean from the two thoughts? I am just not sure what you mean by them.

The first one to me looks like, add the items in the set, and then multiple them by 2 to the power of the number of items in the set.

The second to me looks like multiplying all the items in the set together.

Is that what you are meaning with those two options?

Comment: It is possible to find two disjoint lists of positive integers that have the same product, the same mean, and the same standard deviation (exact same, no rounding needed), you just may have to use longer lists than you have experimented with, and bigger numbers.

Comment: Those are notations for sum and products, where $i$ iterates over elements of set $S$. It might be better to check it on example, say $S=\{1,3,7\}$. First suggestion gives $2^1+2^3+2^7=2+8+128=138$. The second suggestion gives $p_1p_3p_7=2\cdot 5\cdot 17=170$ (as first prime is $2$, third prime is $5$, etc)